# Calling Wordpress functions inside a custom class

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created PHP object to better let me handle my custom posts. In the object I have a function that will populate the object based on the wordpress post.

```
public function ByPost($post) {
    $this->ID = $post->ID;
    $this->Title = $post->post_title;
    $this->Slug = $post->post_name;
    $this->Description = $post->post_content;
    $this->AlbumID = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'albumid', true );
    return $this;
}
```

I then call this method from the loop.

```
$album = Album::Get()->ByPost($post);
```

The problem that I am having is that the get_post_meta function isn't working. If I call it outside of the object it works, but within the object I don't get anything. I don't even get a PHP error. I am assuming there is either a namespace reference or something that I am missing, but I don't have any idea what is causing this.

Comment: What have you tried in debugging this so far? eg. does the function get called but not return anything?

Comment: it doesnt do anything. if i use var_dump(). it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Inside function, define `$post` as global and use `$post->ID`

```
global $post;
$this->AlbumID = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sandbox_description', true );
```

You also need to change function argument name.

change `function ByPost($post){` to `function ByPost($post_new){` or something else and store data in array.

```
public function ByPost($post_new) {
    global $post;
    $data = array();
    $data['Title'] = $post_new->post_title;
    $data['Slug'] = $post_new->post_name;
    $data['Description'] = $post_new->post_content;
    $data['AlbumID'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sandbox_description', true );
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: this needs to work when there isnt a global post object. as in i want to be able to generate a list of object and so on.

Comment: i tried it there, didnt work. $post is passed as a variable into the method so  the function does not need global scope. It must be something to do with the class being static

Comment: Just rename the argument name ByPost($post) to ByPost($post1) or something. It will work.

Comment: @DanHastings As Ravi was getting at, using `$post` again as your argument is probably going to cause issues. Use a fresh variable name. Also double check in your DB that the post meta is actually there with that name too...